# How to convert base64 variable to plain number in django template?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Let's say, we have the following place in the django template:

```
<a href="{% settings_value "BASE_URL" %}{% url 'password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}{% if link_query_params %}?{{ link_query_params }}{% endif %}" target="_blank">
```

How to convert uid to the plain int number in place?

Comment: I don't understand why you want to do that, by encoding it on a base64, you have a (much) shorter id.

Comment: It's because of constraints of the external service.